# Display a table using for twig

Tags: html, symfony, pdf, html-table, twig

I'm using symfony and html2pdf bundle to generate a pdf file so here's the code that I used to display a table in the pdf file:

```
 <table class="border" width="100%" align="center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>Kilometrage</th>
             <th>Liste des Interventions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            {% if voitures.kilometrage-voitures.kilometragederniervidange<20000 and voitures.kilometrage-voitures.kilometragederniervidange>=10000%}                            
            {% for intervention1 in interventions1 %}
                <td>{{ voitures.kilometragederniervidange+10000 }}</td>
                <td>***{{ intervention1.interventions }}</td>
            {% endfor %}{% endif %} 

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here's what I get as a result:

[image]

and what I want to do is to show each line separately. What should I do exactly? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably misplaced the for cycle, try this:

```
 <table class="border" width="100%" align="center">
     <thead>
         <tr>
              <th>Kilometrage</th>
              <th>Liste des Interventions</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         {% if voitures.kilometrage-voitures.kilometragederniervidange<20000 and voitures.kilometrage-voitures.kilometragederniervidange>=10000%}                            
             {% for intervention1 in interventions1 %}
             <tr>     
                 <td>{{ voitures.kilometragederniervidange+10000 }}</td>
                 <td>***{{ intervention1.interventions }}</td>
             </tr>
             {% endfor %}
         {% endif %} 
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

This will insert new table row for every record / run of the for cycle.